# PHP Dropdown, How to get selected text?

Tags: php, dropdown

I have following dropdown-box:

```
$types = array('Article','Preface','Review');
$type = isset($_POST['type']) && in_array($_POST['type'],$types)?$_POST['type']:'Article';

echo '<select name="type">';
foreach($types as $option) {
     echo '<option value="'.$option.'"'.(strcmp($option,$type)==0?' selected="selected"':'').'>'.$option.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

now I want to get the text to a function which sends an email
(the email works, I have tested it with other fields.

```
function my_func($type, $option, $types){
$mailtext = "Type: $type OPTIONS: $option TYPES: $types,";  
mail ($email,
      "",
      $mailtext,
      "From: ..."
      );
mail ("fg@e.de",
      "",
      $mailtext,
      "From:..."
      );
}
```

However, the result in type and types is empty and options are some gibberish and I do not get what the dropdown menu exactly does

Comment: You'd get it in the same way you would any other form post i.e. `$_POST['type']`.

Comment: In your first code snippet it looks like you already know how to get a posted form value.  It's not clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

thank you. the problem was that i mixed up the order of my variables, so the variable which I got was not the right one (mixed up the order of $controlnumber and $version).

```
function mail_control ($email, $gender, $firstname, $lastname, $controlnumber, $version)

mail_control ( $_GET['email'],
                         $_GET['gender'],
                         $_GET['firstname'],
                         $_GET['lastname'],
                         $_GET['version'],
                         $_GET['controlnumber']);
```